# TypeError: object of type 'Message' has no len()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.9

I have created a "Password Cracker" where we can put a password and the program find it. But i want to include it in my discord bot in python, i have tested to put the entire program in the program of my bot but i have an error and i don't know how i can resolve it.

`

```
import random

@bot.command(name="password_cracker")
async def passCrack(message):
  chars = "azertyuiopmlkjhgfdsqwxcvbn1234567890AZERTYUIOPMLKJHGFDSQWXCVBN"
  chars_list = list(chars)

  await message.channel.send("Mot de Passe : ")
  password = await bot.wait_for("message")
  guess_password = ""
  number = 0

  while guess_password != password:
      guess_password = random.choices(chars_list, k=len(password))
      number = number + 1

      if guess_password == list(password):
          await message.channel.send("Your Password Is: " + "".join(guess_password))
          await message.channel.send("We have tested " + str(number) + " possibility")
          break
#My error in the terminal

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lussa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\lussa\Documents\BotdiscordPython\main.py", line 68, in passCrack
    guess_password = random.choices(chars_list, k=len(password))
TypeError: object of type 'Message' has no len()
```

`

I have tested to convert the password to str or to put "len" in the def passCrack but nothing.

Comment: Try examining `password` after assigning to it.  You're treating it as if it were a string, but the error message indicates its an instance of a `Message`.  If you want to extract a string from it, get that working before trying to run your `while` loop.

Comment: i don't know how i can do this i am new in python

Comment: In that case, the best thing to do is to start using a debugger so you can see what the actual content of message is.